# using python text toi speech to activate tkinter buttons

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm writing a program that allows the user to trigger tkinter widget using their voice.  For example if the user says "Select Steam"  the Steam button is triggered.  My problem is I can get either the voice recognition to work OR the GUI to show.  I'm stuck as how to get them to work together.  I've tried threading and multiprocessing and neither runs the 2 functions in parallel.  Any guidance is appreciated.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
from tkinter import *
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from multiprocessing import Process


def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
    engine.say(text)
    print(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        greeting = "Stand by mode active."
        print(greeting)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        data = ""
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition did not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Request Failed; {0}".format(e))
    return data

def assistant():
    query = listen()
    print(speak)
    if "select steam" in query:
        speak("selecting steam")
        Launcher.frmSteam.focus()
    
    elif "select battlenet" in query:
        speak("selecting battlenet")
        Launcher.frmBnet.focus()
    
    elif "exit program" in query:
        speak("goodbye")
        exit()

class Launcher():
    root = tb.Window(themename='vapor')
    root.title("VEDA")
    root.geometry('')
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.8)

    frmLauncher = tb.LabelFrame(root)
    frmLauncher.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)

    ntbLauncher = tb.Notebook(frmLauncher, bootstyle="info")
    ntbLauncher.grid(row=0, column=0)

    frmSteam = tb.Frame(ntbLauncher)
    frmBnet = tb.Frame(ntbLauncher)
    frmProduc = tb.Frame(ntbLauncher)

    ntbLauncher.add(frmSteam, text="STEAM")
    ntbLauncher.add(frmBnet, text="BATTLE.NET")
    ntbLauncher.add(frmProduc, text="PRODUCTIVITY")

    root.mainloop()

process1 = Process(target=assistant).start()
process2 = Process(target=Launcher).start()
```

Comment: See [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).  You cannot call function from other process directly.